# The method getProperty(String) is undefined for the type Properties

Tags: java, properties, compiler-errors

I have DBUtil class which contains the configuration of database. I have property file which contains the DB details. I am trying to load the property file with this class but I am getting an error on load() method saying `The method getProperty(String) is undefined for the type Properties`. I really dont know what is wrong.

**DBUtil class**

```html
package com.varun.util;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.Connection;
import com.sun.xml.fastinfoset.sax.Properties;

public class DbUtil {
 
 private static Connection connection = null;
 public static Connection getConnection(){
  if(connection!=null)
  {
   return connection;
  }
  else
  {
   try{
    
    Properties prop=new Properties();
    InputStream inputStream=DbUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/db.properties");
    prop.load(inputStream); // The method load(InputStream) is undefined for the type Properties
    String driver =  prop.getProp("");//The method getProp(String) is undefined for the type Properties
                String url = prop.getProperty("url");//The method getProperty(String) is undefined for the type Properties
                String user = prop.getProperty("user"); //The method getProperty(String) is undefined for the type Properties
                String password = prop.getProperty("password"); //The method getProperty(String) is undefined for the type Properties
                Class.forName(driver);
                connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    
   }catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
   {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
   catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
   return connection;
  }
 }

}
```

I have commented the error along with the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `import java.util.Properties;` and you have imported the wrong class  - `com.sun.xml.fastinfoset.sax.Properties`

The classes are called the same but they are in different package. You probably use some IDE that automatically does your imports and it has imported the wrong type.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you've imported the wrong `Properties`.

Try swapping out

```
import com.sun.xml.fastinfoset.sax.Properties;
```

for

```
import java.util.Properties;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the import line :

```
import com.sun.xml.fastinfoset.sax.Properties;
```

With:

```
import java.util.Properties;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the import instead of `import com.sun.xml.fastinfoset.sax.Properties` use `import java.util.Properties`